# paypal result not getting on mobile browsers in php

Tags: php, jquery

When I am testing this Website code on desktop browsers this is posting paypal data back on return url perfectly. But when I am testing same website code on my Mobile browser payapl is not posting back any data on return url. It just get back on return url without any data..

Could you please help me someone???

Advance thanks for helping.

Comment: no code, no idea. Plus, what type of "mobile" are we talking about here? Must be 5,000 different models out there.

Comment: nice line @Fred-ii- .....:D

Comment: @SHAZ glad to see I made one person smile. It was all worthwhile ;-)

Comment: btw, as a side note: for important things you should rely on the IPN, not on the parameters added to the return URL